# how to make vmware workstation connect to esxi with a http proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, vmware, vmware-workstation, esxi

sorry that english is not my mother language，something is translated by google...

---

i setup a new exsi (also calld vSphere Hypervisor ?) in a lan

> vmware workstation 17 and exsi 8

---

if i use a pc under the same lan , workstation can connect exsi and workes well.
but if i use my laptop outside the lan and use a http proxy to access the exsi in the lan:

- i use the http proxy as windows system proxy
- i can access the web panel of exsi normally

**but now i try to use workstation to connect exsi,

self-designed certificate warnings can be displayed,but when i go on,it just tell me timeout after minutes.**

---

- if i tried to connect a nonexistence ip ,it tell me a security error occurred while connecting to the server
- i don't want to use answer like process hook or tun/tap

---

*its my first question here,let me know if i do sth wrong...*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: if i use another pc in the same lan with workstation to connect exsi ,it workes well.
but if i use my laptop , it outside the lan ....   I think you may have an IP addressing issue. The first case is likely using Bridged networking. Your second case probably needs to change to NAT.